# Embed Video Stream in Ncurses

Tags: user-interface, video-streaming, ncurses

I really like the look and idea of ncurses, and I was wondering if there was a way to include a video stream embedded in a ncurses gui. If not, is there any other gui method I can use that  I can make look like ncurses available for python or C++?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? Text terminals don't do a very good job with video output.

Comment: I'd love to hear additional suggestions on hat would be good for this

Comment: What can you assume of the output device? If it's a GUI terminal emulator you may be able make a GUI video player look like it's embedded in the terminal window. If it's the linux console you may be able to use the console framebuffer.

Comment: Do you have any general suggestions for guis then? I'm building a single purpose mobile robot control system based on the raspberry pi, and I was just imagining video embedded in a terminal like window. I have full access to the x windows system for all of this

Answer (score 1):

Although I doubt you would find it useful for any practical purpose, you can embed a video stream in an ncurses window using [libcaca](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/libcaca) (a [short, basic tutorial](http://caca.zoy.org/doxygen/libcaca/libcaca-tutorial.html) is available, although it doesn't discuss video).